# Meaning of "to will a parking spot"

Tags: meaning-in-context

A guy is bragging about a great parking spot he has gotten in front of the building. And he says:

> I am just *willing* these great parking spots.

What does it mean?

Comment: Was it a confident native speaker?  Because it could just be a mistake.  While *"I am willing these parking spots into existence."* could be a valid interpretation if you give leeway, someone trying to be funny would say that whole statement--this contraction would be very unusual and the sentence winds up as borderline nonsense.

Comment: @HostileFork: It is from *Seinfeld*. George Costanza said it.

Comment: @Graduate: Ah, well then I'll delete that comment (and this one too in a few hours).

Comment: @Cornstalks: Actually the additional sentences you gave could help to understand the meaning, because they made the context richer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a figure of speech. He is essentially saying that he's wanting a good parking spot so badly that his desire alone is making the spots available, as if that is some sort of superpower.

It's intended to be a humorous way to express a feeling of triumph.

Comment: "so badly" - not implied by the expression, speculation.
The expression is self praise, not an evidence of dire need.

Comment: Uri - I never said anything about dire need. Humans are quite capable of wanting something badly even when they don't _need_ it; 25 years as a parent have taught me that ;^) That said, I'll grant that "desire" is something I've infused, but I find it hard to believe that anyone – even George Costanza – could "will" something flippantly, at least, not when they felt apathetic about it. The word "will" implies some measure of determination.

Answer (score 18):

He probably means

> I am *willing* these parking spots *into existence*.

i.e.,

> I am *creating* these parking spots *by the force of my will* (volition).

which, of course, is not literally true.

Answer (score 10):

The context suggests that this wasn't the intended meaning in this case but, "to will a parking spot" could also mean

> "to bequeath a parking space to someone by the terms of a will"

In a densely populated city in which parking spaces are valuable, it would not be unheard of for someone to leave a parking space they owned to an heir when they died.

Comment: I don't think this is the intended meaning, but your answer shows how tricky English can be, and why surrounding context is so important. _To my niece Belinda, I leave you the parking spot just around the corner from the downtown market_... – See? I am just **willing** these great parking spots - lol :^)

Answer (score 2):

It is his way of emphasizing the intensity of his desire.
He is wishing for a great parking spot just like one of these.

Answer (score 2):

Scott nailed it unless you're not sure if he said 'willed it into the spot'. You have to 'will' cars into tight parking spaces. You must believe its going to fit, because it will fit. Then you just have to (will it into place) make it fit.

Answer (score 0):

He will never give the parking space up! He will die before doing so. Others acknowledge his asset enough to want it gifted in his will, so he might even be open to bribery and grovelling :). This a macho-dominance thing, not a fantasy-wish thing, I'll bet. Besides, he said this AFTER getting the parking spot, not before. I agree with Blah. I've used such language (albeit not over a parking spot!) on occasion...

Comment: An interesting take, but I think an 'act of will' is meant, not a testamentary disposition :)